# FATAL: failed to create INET domain socket in PGPOOL2

Tags: postgresql, load-balancing, pgpool

```
   priyank@infahmcpu0010:/etc/pgpool2$ pgpool -n 

2022-06-20 18:48:40.282: main pid 33987: LOG:  reading status file: 1 th backend is set to down status
2022-06-20 18:48:40.282: main pid 33987: LOG:  health_check_stats_shared_memory_size: requested size: 12288
2022-06-20 18:48:40.282: main pid 33987: LOG:  memory cache initialized
2022-06-20 18:48:40.282: main pid 33987: DETAIL:  memcache blocks :64
2022-06-20 18:48:40.282: main pid 33987: LOG:  allocating (136981824) bytes of shared memory segment
2022-06-20 18:48:40.282: main pid 33987: LOG:  allocating shared memory segment of size: 136981824 
2022-06-20 18:48:40.340: main pid 33987: LOG:  health_check_stats_shared_memory_size: requested size: 12288
2022-06-20 18:48:40.340: main pid 33987: LOG:  health_check_stats_shared_memory_size: requested size: 12288
2022-06-20 18:48:40.340: main pid 33987: LOG:  memory cache initialized
2022-06-20 18:48:40.340: main pid 33987: DETAIL:  memcache blocks :64
2022-06-20 18:48:40.341: main pid 33987: LOG:  pool_discard_oid_maps: discarded memqcache oid maps
2022-06-20 18:48:40.344: main pid 33987: LOG:  Setting up socket for 0.0.0.0:9999
2022-06-20 18:48:40.344: main pid 33987: FATAL:  failed to create INET domain socket
2022-06-20 18:48:40.344: main pid 33987: DETAIL:  bind on socket failed with error "Address already in use"
2022-06-20 18:48:40.347: main pid 33987: LOG:  shutting down
```

all configuration are done but whenever starting pgpool2 getting error

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the log

`2022-06-20 18:48:40.344: main pid 33987: DETAIL:  bind on socket failed with error "Address already in use"`

You need to stop already running instance using command

`pgpool stop`